# How to binding data in swift?

Tags: swift, mvvm, data-binding, rx-swift

I'm going to show the view the data I got from the server. An error occurred while developing using Rxswift and MVVM. The id value must be received from the product model, and an error occurs in this part.

```
extension SelectViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        print("Tap")
        let detailVC = DetailViewController()

        detailVC.product = products[indexPath.row]
        detailVC.productId = products[indexPath.row].id

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailPassVC, animated: true)
    }
}
```

This is the code for the part that passes the id value. `detailVC.product = products[indexPath.row]`An error occurs in this area. error message is "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range"

```
    var products:[ProductModel] = []
    var product = ProductModel()
    var productId = Int()

    func initViewModel() {
        let input = DetailViewModel.Input(loadDetailData: getData.asSignal(onErrorJustReturn: ()), id: productId)
        let output = viewModel.transform(input: input)
        
        output.loadDetail.asObservable().bind(onNext: { data in
            self.infoLabel.text = data?.detailDescription
            self.passView.setData(data!)
            self.secondView.setData(data!)
            self.fareView.setData(data!)
            self.totalLabel.text = totalPrice(data!)
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
```

This is the code for the part where the view model is bound.
And This is my viewmodel code

```
class DetailViewModel: BaseViewModel {
    private let repo = ProductRepository()
    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
        
    struct Input {
        let loadDetailData: Signal<Void>
        let id: Int

    }
    struct Output {
        let loadDetail: Driver<DetailModel?>
        let error: Driver<String?>
    }
    
    func transform(input: Input) -> Output {
        let loadDetail = PublishSubject<DetailModel?>()
        let msg= PublishSubject<String?>()
        
        input.loadDetailData.asObservable()
            .flatMap { self.productRepo.detailProduct(input.id)}
            .subscribe(onNext: { data in
                switch data {
                case let .success(detail):
                    loadDetail.onNext(detail)
                default:
                    errorMessage.onNext("load fail")
                }
            }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
        
        return Output(loadDetail: loadDetail.asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: nil),error: msg.asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: nil))
    }
}
```

How can I send the ID value?

Comment: Where do you assign to `products`?

Comment: @DanielT. It is assigned from the tableview delete attribute on the previous screen.
```    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        print("Tap")
        let detailVC = DetailViewController()

        detailVC.product = products[indexPath.row]
        detailVC.productId = products[indexPath.row].id

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: That's where you assign `product`. Where do you assign `products`?

Comment: And there should not be any Subjects in your view model, nor should there be a DisposeBag. You don't need them.